# How to find road distance between points from two shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, road

I am new to QGIS, but have to find the distance between centroids of NJ municipalities (which I have as a shapefile) and the nearest road sign which is also its own shapefile, along the roads of the state.
I have three shapefiles: one road shapefile, and two point shapefiles and my goal is to find the road distance between points of the two point shapefiles.
I have tried the RoadGraph plugin but I do not want to have to manually click each point since I have to know the nearest sign to each centroid first.